# IntelliJ is showing print Output wrong

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I try to print a triangle "/\" in Java using IntelliJ, I encounter a problem that the console is not showing what I want, instead it underlines the triangle as if it were a link. I am told that this is a problem on IntelliJ's behalf but I don't know how to print it normal without the underlined "linked" stuff.

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("/\\");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [known issue in IntelliJ IDEA](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-184011/Non-URLs-are-linkified-in-the-Run-console). It provides hyperlinks to the files where it shouldn't. The link/URL is causing the underline.

As a workaround, you can [disable the Groovy plug-in](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html#disable-plugin) and restart the IDE.

Another workaround would be to disable the **Underscored** effect for hyperlinks at Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Color Scheme | General | **Hyperlinks**.

[image: link]